# expectation and variance of future stock price under binary tree

Tags: python, statistics, probability, finance, quantitative-finance

Probably a over-simplified model for stock price: on each day, the price will go up by a factor 1.05 with probability 0.6 or will go down to 1/1.05 with probability 0.4. So this is a non-symmetrical binary tree. How can I analytically calculate the expectation and variance of this stock price on future date, say day 100. Also, is there any module in python to handle binary tree model like this? appreciate code to implement this.

Best regards

Comment: The analysis is probably simpler if you take the logarithm of the price, so instead of a product, it's a summation. The distribution of log(price) after 100 days is going to be well-approximated by a Gaussian, so the distribution of price is going to be lognormal. From that you can get the properties you need.

Comment: fantastic idea, thank you @RobertDodier

Answer (score 1):

```
import random as r
s = 100 # starting value
```

^^Initial conditions. Simulating one day on the stock market:

```
def day(stock_value): #One day in the stock market
    k = r.uniform(0,1)
    if k < 0.6:
        output = 1.05*stock_value
    else:
        output = stock_value/1.05
    return(output)
```

Simulating 100 days on the stock market:

```
for j in range(100): #simulates 100 days in the stock market
    s = day(s)
    print(s)
```

Simulating 100 days 1000 times:

```
data = []
for i in range(1000):
    s = [100]
    for j in range(100): 
        s.append(day(s[j]))
    data.append(s)
```

Converting the data to only consider the last day:

```
def mnnm(mat): #Makes an mxn matrix into an nxm matrix
    out = []
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
        out.append([])
    for j in range(len(mat[0])):
        for m in range(len(mat)):
            out[j].append(mat[m][j])
    return(out)

data = mnnm(data)
data = data[-1]
```

Taking a mean average:

```
def lst_avg(lst): #Returns the average of a list
    output = 0
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        output+= lst[j]/len(lst)
    return(output)
mean = lst_avg(data)
```

Variance:

```
import numpy as np
for h in range(len(data)):
    data[h] = data[h]**2
mean_square = lst_avg(data)
variance = np.fabs(mean_square - mean**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical value after 1 day is (assuming value on day 0 is A)

A * 0.6 * 1.05 + 100 * 0.4/1.05

And after 100 days it's

A * (0.603 + 0.380952...)**100 so...

(in the following I use 1 as stock price on day 0.)

```
p1 = 0.6
p2 = 0.4
x1 = 1.05
x2 = 1/1.05

initial_value = 1
no_of_days = 100

# 1 day
expected_value_after_1_day = initial_value * ( p1*x1 + p2*x2)  
print (expected_value_after_1_day, 'is the expected value of price after 1 day')
ex_squared_value_1_day = initial_value * (p1*x1**2 + p2*x2**2)
# variance can be calculated as follows
variance_day_1 = ex_squared_value_1_day - expected_value_after_1_day**2
# or an alternative calculation, summing the squares of the differences from the mean
alt_variance_day_1 = p1 * (x1 - expected_value_after_1_day) ** 2 + p2 * (x2 - expected_value_after_1_day) ** 2
print ('Variance after one day is', variance_day_1)

# 100 days
expected_value_n_days = initial_value * (p1*x1 + p2*x2) ** no_of_days 
ex_squared_value_n_days = initial_value * (p1*x1**2 + p2*x2**2) ** no_of_days
ex_value_n_days_squared = expected_value_n_days ** 2
variance_n_days = ex_squared_value_n_days - ex_value_n_days_squared

print(expected_value_n_days, 'is the expected value of price after {} days'.format(no_of_days))
print(ex_squared_value_n_days, 'is the expected value of the square of the price after {} days'.format(no_of_days))
print(ex_value_n_days_squared, 'is the square of the expected value of the price after {} days'.format(no_of_days))
print(variance_n_days, 'is the variance after {} days'.format(no_of_days))
```

It probably looks a bit old-school, hope you don't mind!

Output

```
1.0109523809523808 is the expected value of price after 1 day
Variance after one day is 0.0022870748299321786
2.972144657651404 is the expected value of price after 100 days
11.046309656223373 is the expected value of the square of the price after 100 days
8.833643866005783 is the square of the expected value of the price after 100 days
2.2126657902175904 is the variance after 100 days
```